# How to use date-picker in asp text-box using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use date-picker in asp text-box but i get an error when i run it in IE " Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery".  When i render it in Chrome i don't get any error but the date-picker does not show up at all.  However, if i add class ="date" in the text-box, the date-picker works in Chrome but not in IE.

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dp = $('#<%=txtDT_Particip.ClientID%>');
            dp.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
                language: "tr"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });
        });
</script>
```

this does not work at all in any browser

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDT_Particip" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Select preferred date to start" ></asp:TextBox>
```

this works only in chrome

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDT_Particip" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Select preferred date to start"  type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a reference to jQuery i.e.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Check the below, which works in both IE and Chrome.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xjmxxch/2/)**

Comment: thanks, it works in chrome but not in IE 10.  I am using asp.net text-box control and i am getting this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'  please help.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference jQuery UI along with the base jQuery library.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/